# Django - Store username of logged on user in admin edits

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm using django as the edit interface for a database, and want to track the last edit. I've got the following class

```
class CommonInformation(models.Model):
    lastEditedOn = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null = True, blank=True)
    lastEditedby = models.ForeignKey(Person,null = True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

which I can use to track the edit date, but is there a way to make it automatically store the username of the person logged onto the admin site instead of having to manually select the name each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the admin site you can use [save_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) in your admin file e.g.

```
class CommonInformationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ....
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.lastEditedby = request.user
        obj.save()
```